# Why I can't read text from URL with KTOR client?

Tags: kotlin, ktor

I want to read a text from a URL with KTOR client.

```
suspend fun fetch() : String {
    val client = HttpClient(CIO)
    return client.get(ENDPOINT)
}
```

but it gives me a Type mismatch. Required:String. Found:HttpResponse.

I did the same thing with:

```
suspend fun fetch() : String {
    return URL(ENDPOINT).readText()
}
```

how can do it with KTOR client?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [the doc on receiving responses](https://ktor.io/docs/response.html).

Since Ktor 2, `client.get(...)` returns an `HttpResponse` instance, and then you can read the body explicitly using `.body()`:

```kotlin
suspend fun fetch() : String {
    val client = HttpClient(CIO)
    return client.get(ENDPOINT).body()
}
```

The `body()` method is generic and the return type depends on the expected expression type. You can make it explicit by using `.body<String>()`, especially in contexts where the compiler cannot guess.

Note that you shouldn't create a new client on the fly every time you make a request. Clients need resources like thread pools, and it's best if they are reused.

Comment: Hi @Joffrey, Can you please help me on this [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/q/75367786/8266651).